# Is there a limit on the number of classes in mllib NaiveBayes? Error calling model.save()

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, naivebayes, apache-spark-ml

I am trying to train a model to predict the category of text input data. I am running into what seems to be numerical instability using the `pyspark.ml.classification.NaiveBayes` classifier on a bag-of-words when the number of classes is above a certain amount.

In my real world project, I have on the order of ~1bn records and ~50 classes. I am able to train my model and make predictions but I get an error when I try to save it using `model.save()`. Operationally, this is annoying since I have to retrain my model each time from scratch.

In trying to debug, I scaled my data down to around ~10k rows and had the same issue trying to save. However saving works fine if I reduce the number of class labels.

This leads me to believe that there is a limit to the number of labels. I am not able to reproduce my exact issues, but the code below is related. If I set `num_labels` to anything greater than 31, `model.fit()` throws an error.

My questions:

1. Is there a limit to the number of classes in the `mllib` implementation of `NaiveBayes`?
2. What could be some reasons that I am not able to save my model if I can successfully use it to make predictions?
3. If there is indeed a limit, would it be possible to split my data into groups of smaller classes, train separate models, and combine?

#### Full Working Example

**Create some dummy data.**

I'm going to use `nltk.corpus.comparitive_sentences` and `nltk.corpus.sentence_polarity`. Keep in mind that this is just an illustrative example with nonsense data - I'm not concerned with the performance of the fitted model.

```
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

# create some dummy data
from nltk.corpus import comparative_sentences, sentence_polarity
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'sentence': [" ".join(s) for s in cs.sents() + sp.sents()]
    }
)

# assign a 'category' to each row
num_labels = 31  # seems to be the upper limit
df['category'] = (df.index%num_labels).astype(str)

# make it into a spark dataframe
spark_df = sqlCtx.createDataFrame(df)
```

**Data Preparation Pipeline**

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import NGram, Tokenizer, StopWordsRemover
from pyspark.ml.feature import HashingTF, IDF, StringIndexer, VectorAssembler
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vector

indexer = StringIndexer(inputCol='category', outputCol='label')
tokenizer = Tokenizer(inputCol="sentence", outputCol="sentence_tokens")
remove_stop_words = StopWordsRemover(inputCol="sentence_tokens", outputCol="filtered")
unigrammer = NGram(n=1, inputCol="filtered", outputCol="tokens") 
hashingTF = HashingTF(inputCol="tokens", outputCol="hashed_tokens")
idf = IDF(inputCol="hashed_tokens", outputCol="tf_idf_tokens")

clean_up = VectorAssembler(inputCols=['tf_idf_tokens'], outputCol='features')

data_prep_pipe = Pipeline(
    stages=[indexer, tokenizer, remove_stop_words, unigrammer, hashingTF, idf, clean_up]
)
transformed = data_prep_pipe.fit(spark_df).transform(spark_df)
clean_data = transformed.select(['label','features'])
```

**Train the model**

```
from pyspark.ml.classification import NaiveBayes
nb = NaiveBayes()
(training,testing) = clean_data.randomSplit([0.7,0.3], seed=12345)
model = nb.fit(training)
test_results = model.transform(testing)
```

**Evaluate Model**

```
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import MulticlassClassificationEvaluator
acc_eval = MulticlassClassificationEvaluator()
acc = acc_eval.evaluate(test_results)
print("Accuracy of model at predicting label was: {}".format(acc))
```

On my machine, this prints:

```
Accuracy of model at predicting label was: 0.0305764788269
```

**Error Message**

If I change `num_labels` to 32 or higher, this is the error I get when I call `model.fit()`:

> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1336.fit. :
>   org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
>   Task 0 in stage 86.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task
>   0.3 in stage 86.0 (TID 1984, someserver.somecompany.net, executor 22): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Kryo serialization failed: Buffer
>   overflow. Available: 7, required: 8 Serialization trace: values
>   (org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.DenseVector). To avoid this, increase
>   spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max value.
>   ...
>   ...
>   blah blah blah more java stuff that goes on forever

#### Notes

- In this example, if I add a feature for bigrams, the error happens if `num_labels` > 15. I wonder if it is coincidence that this is also 1 less than a power of 2.
- In my real-world project, I also get an error when trying to call `model.theta`. (I don't think the errors themselves are meaningful - they are just the exceptions passed back from the java/scala methods.)

Comment: _blah blah blah more java stuff that goes on forever_ is most of the time the thing you should focus on and typically it is the thing we need :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hard limitations**:

Number of features * Number of classes has to be lower `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (2<sup>31</sup> - 1). You are nowhere near these value.

**Soft limitations**:

Theta matrix (conditional probabilities) is of size Number of features * Number of classes. Theta is stored both locally on the driver (as a part of the model) and serialized and send to the workers. This means that all machines require at least enough memory to serialize or deserialize and store the result.

Since you use default settings for `HashingTF.numFeatures` (2<sup>20</sup>) each additional class adds 262144 - it is not that much, but quickly adds up. Based on the partial traceback you've posted, it looks like the failing component is Kryo serializer. The same traceback also suggests the solution, which is increasing `spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max`.

You can also try using standard Java serialization by setting:

```
 spark.serializer org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializer
```

Since you use PySpark with `pyspark.ml` and `pyspark.sql` it might be acceptable without significant performance loss.

Configuration aside I would focus on the feature engineering component. Using binary `CountVetorizer` (see note about `HashingTF` below) with `ChiSqSelector` might provide one way to both increase interpretability and effectively reduce number of features. You may also consider more sophisticated approaches (determine feature importances and applying Naive Bayes only on a subset of data, more advanced text processing like lemmatization / stemming, or using some variant of autoencoder to get more compact vector representation).

**Notes**:

- Please keep in mind that multinational Naive Bayes considers only binary features. `NaiveBayes` will handle this internally, but I would still recommend using `setBinary` for clarity.
- Arguably `HashingTF` is rather useless here. Hash collisions aside, highly sparse features and essentially meaningless features, make it poor choice as a preprocessing step for `NaiveBayes`.

Comment: I see, so the problem is a memory issue during the serialization. That explains why I can make predictions but I can't save the model. Is the only solution to increase buffer size? Any insight on training separate models on subsets of the data and combining them?

Comment: Maybe I can train some n models, then use each to predict and pick the class with the highest probability.

Comment: You'd have to step through stack trace to figure out who to blame. In general closures never use KryoSerializer, only data. So it hits you when theta is serialized for writes (we use `DataFrames` here). You can also disable Kryo serialization (it has limited applications in PySpark anyway). But I would rather focus on feature engineering - IMHO > 200k features, are way to much in practice to get intepretable model.

Comment: This is all very useful information. Last question- do you have any links to docs for this stuff? I've never seen the `setBinary` flag- never knew that was an option.

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.feature.HashingTF and https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.classification.NaiveBayes?