# Is there a size limit for Spark's RDD

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

Do spark's RDD have a limit in size?

As for my specific case, can a RDD have 2^400 colums?

Comment: @philantrovert https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48234474/is-there-a-limit-on-the-number-of-classes-in-mllib-naivebayes-error-calling-mod dupes ?

Comment: not sure, this naivebayes output uses RDD though so the answer to my question might me 2^31

Comment: @eliasah I'm not sure either. :D

Comment: that is the answer to your question @ArditMeti and that's why I wanted to close it as a dupe even though it's not an exact dupe :)

Comment: unless you want to delete your question @ArditMeti

Comment: one more thing, with scala 2.10 a tuple is limited to 22 entry as it's considered as a case class. A purist might say that this is not accurate but I'm not one

Comment: I will keep it up for a couple of hours, if no one answers I'll delete it then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically RDD doesn't have a size limit. Neither it has any limit on number of columns you can store. However there is a limitation from SPARK which allows each RDD partition to be capped at 2GB. [See Here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-6235)

So, you can store the 2^400 columns in a RDD. As long as each partition size is less than 2GB.

Now there are practical problems associated with having 2^400. Because you have to adhere current spark limitation , with huge number of columns you would need to repartition the data in to large number of partitions. This probably reduce the efficiency.

Answer (score 3):

The first part of Avishek's answer is a bit out of date as of Spark 2.4.0. At time of writing, almost all of the 2GB limits throughout the Spark source have been resolved: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-6235. That being said, your table width is still problematic.

In practicality, your RDD is likely going to be guaranteed poor read/write times even when each partitions has only a single row, 2^400 is still an enormous number! Conservatively assuming each col has 10 bytes of data, a single row has approx:

```
  (10 bytes / col) * 2.6 * 10^120 cols
= 2.6 * 10^121 bytes
= 2.6 * 10^112 gigabytes
```

That is huge! Do you really need 2^400 columns?

Comment: So as you mentioned since the 6235 issue has been resolved, is it possible for me to have just one fat object of say 40GB in each partition of the RDD?

Comment: @awadhesh14 most of the time, Spark data is coming from HDFS or other distributed data store, 99.9999% of time, data is already partitionned (HDFS = block , elasticsearch = shard etc...), so if you have a 40G partition, there is something wrong in your plan ^^