# Python Pandas to PySpark: How to tokenize, remove stopgap words, and do trigrams in PySpark

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, nlp, nltk

I have the following sample data frame below.  I execute Python Pandas code in my Jupyter Notebook.

```
No  category    problem_definition
175 2521       ['coffee', 'maker', 'brewing', 'properly', '2', '420', '420', '420']
211 1438       ['galley', 'work', 'table', 'stuck']
912 2698       ['cloth', 'stuck']
572 2521       ['stuck', 'coffee']
```

I used the code below to tokenize my text column:

```
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize 
import pandas as pd 
import re 

df['problem_definition_tokenized'] = df['problem_definition'].apply(word_tokenize)
```

I use the code below to remove stopgap words:

```
set(stopwords.words('english'))

stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))

df['problem_definition_stopwords'] = df['problem_definition_tokenized'].apply(lambda x: [i for i in x if i not in stop_words])
```

Next, I calculated trigrams using collocations package.

```
import nltk
from nltk.collocations import *

bigram_measures = nltk.collocations.BigramAssocMeasures()
trigram_measures = nltk.collocations.TrigramAssocMeasures()

finder = BigramCollocationFinder.from_documents(df['problem_definition_stopwords'])

finder.apply_freq_filter(8) 

finder.nbest(trigram_measures.pmi, 100) 

s = pd.Series(df['problem_definition_stopwords'])

from nltk import ngrams
from collections import Counter

ngram_list = [pair for row in s for pair in ngrams(row, 3)]

counts = Counter(ngram_list).most_common()

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(counts, columns=['gram', 'count'])

df
```

The result looks like this ... "xxx" stands for a word

```
gram               count 
(xxx, xxx, xxx)    23
(xxx, xxx, xxx)    14
(xxx, xxx, xxx)    63
(xxx, xxx, xxx)    28
```

I can get all the above code running in Pandas Python but when I try to run this code in a PySpark environment it just keeps spinning.

Is there a way to transpose the code I have written into PySpark code?  I have googled around but couldn't find anything definitive.

Comment: It doesn't provide you a solution, but the example in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48234474/5858851) shows tokenizing, removing stopwords, and making N-grams. You should be able to work with it to get your desired output.

Comment: You can take a look at [Pandas UDF](https://databricks.com/blog/2017/10/30/introducing-vectorized-udfs-for-pyspark.html)